# How to configure logstash in our machine without affecting performance?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I need to use logstash to read some log information from my own system. I'm using elastic search as a output of the logstash. Elastic search will be configured in another server.

I read some articles and discussion forums, they are faced some memory consumption problem while using logstash.

**Reference links:**

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/logstash-users/qIdzJmD6pJ4

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-heap-size/622/6

How can I configure the logstash in my machine without affecting performance?

**My System configurations:**

Windows server 2012

8GB RAM

500GB HDD

Comment: You'll have to configure the max jvm memory to limit the memory consumption and perhaps set the worker threads to one (to limit CPU core usage). But the performance (in term of throughput) of your logstash will be severely limited.

Comment: Also the links are about an older logstash version, 1.4, currently it's version 5.5. And it was a memory leak, affecting one input (tcp), which should have been fixed in 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to make no impact on the system when using logstash. The idea is to make the impact minimum as possible.

Important factors are **pipeline.workers** which depends on cpu cores and **jvm heapsize** which makes impact on memory size.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/tuning-logstash.html

### pipeline.workers

Usually you set the value to grater than equal to number of cores. However, you still can set the number less than your cores. Default setting is it sets to number of cores.

```
From logstash.yml
# This defaults to the number of the host's CPU cores.
#
# pipeline.workers: 2
```

Setting to **1** means you will only have single filter/output queue. Theoretically , logstash will process all events sequentially.

### jvm heap size

Since logstash runs on jvm, setting this too low will make logstash low performance. If I were you , I would stick to default **1GB** .

Hope this helps.